# How to recover missing gdm3 files causing broken login screen on 18.04

Tags: gnome, login, themes, gdm

The gdm3 login screen GUI is broken with odd graphical artifacts and colors. The input field is also often not visible/obscured, but I am able to blindly log into the desktop via Enter > password, and the Gnome DE appears ok. It appears that part of the problem is the missing `usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/assets/login-background.jpg` file per the syslog output below. Don't know if the additional gnome-shell JS errors are relevant. There is no `assets` directory at all, the css and svg files live in `usr/share/gnome-shell/theme` along with some symbolic links to custom themes I installed. No login-background.jpg file anywhere on the system in fact.

Reading other gdm3 questions, I've seen recommendations to reinstall gnome-shell-common to restore gdm3 files but other feedback indicates broken login/themes/etc. with this approach. How can I safely resolve this? Thanks

Syslog:

```
Mar  3 12:41:12 ubu-desk org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2139]: [2641:2641:0303/124112.997066:ERROR:media_internals.cc(112)] Cannot get RenderProcessHost
Mar  3 12:41:14 ubu-desk gnome-shell[2139]: JS ERROR: Exception in callback for signal: activate: Error: Error invoking IBus.set_global_engine_async:
Expected function for callback argument callback, got undefined#012setEngine@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/ibusManager.js:207:
9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012activateInputSource@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/keyboard.js:490:13#012wrapper@
resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_emit@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128:27#012activate@
resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/keyboard.js:65:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_inputSourcesChanged@
resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/keyboard.js:620:13#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012reload@
resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/keyboard.js:369:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_ibusSetContentType@
resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/keyboard.js:691:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_emit@
resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128:27#012_setContentType@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/ibusManager.js:183:9#012wrapper@
resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
[...]
Mar  3 12:43:35 ubu-desk gnome-shell[1522]: Failed to load file:///usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/assets/login-background.jpg: Error opening file /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/assets/login-background.jpg: No such file or directory
Mar  3 12:43:36 ubu-desk gnome-shell[1522]: message repeated 6 times: [ Failed to load file:///usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/assets/login-background.jpg: Error opening file /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/assets/login-background.jpg: No such file or directory]
Mar  3 12:43:36 ubu-desk gsd-color[1780]: failed to set screen _ICC_PROFILE: Failed to open file “/home/user/.local/share/icc/edid-c1a0cd69078353a118ddc74a6c339113.icc”: Permission denied
```

System:

```
Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (up-to-date)
4.18.0-15-generic  (via 18.04.2 HWE stack)

gdm3            3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4
gir1.2-gdm-1.0          3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4
libgdm1             3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4
gnome-control-center        1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2
gnome-initial-setup     3.28.0-2ubuntu6.16.04.4
gnome-menus         3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1
gnome-session-bin       3.28.1-0ubuntu3
gnome-session-canberra      0.30-5ubuntu1
gnome-session-common        3.28.1-0ubuntu3
gnome-settings-daemon       3.28.1-0ubuntu1.1
gnome-settings-daemon-schemas   3.28.1-0ubuntu1.1
gnome-shell         3.28.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.4
gnome-shell-common      3.28.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.4
gnome-shell-extension-appindicator  18.04.1
gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock   0.9.1ubuntu18.04.3
gnome-shell-extensions      3.28.0-2
gnome-software          3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.8
gnome-software-common       3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.8
gnome-software-plugin-snap  3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.8
gnome-themes-extra      3.28-1ubuntu1
gnome-themes-extra-data     3.28-1ubuntu1
gnome-themes-standard       3.28-1ubuntu1
gnome-tweaks            3.28.1-1
```

---

Additional info as requested:

```
$ sudo systemctl status colord
colord.service - Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/colord.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-03-03 18:27:36 EST; 29min ago
 Main PID: 1869 (colord)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/colord.service
           └─1869 /usr/lib/colord/colord

Mar 03 18:27:36 ubu-desk systemd[1]: Starting Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles...
Mar 03 18:27:36 ubu-desk systemd[1]: Started Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles.


$ grep -i colord /var/log/syslog*
/var/log/syslog:Mar  3 11:17:59 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2306]: Failed to enumerate children of /var/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-MZlaaA: Error opening directory '/var/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-MZlaaA': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog:Mar  3 11:17:59 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2306]: Failed to enumerate children of /tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-9wCBts: Error opening directory '/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-9wCBts': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog:Mar  3 12:17:59 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2306]: Failed to enumerate children of /var/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-MZlaaA: Error opening directory '/var/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-MZlaaA': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog:Mar  3 12:17:59 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2306]: Failed to enumerate children of /tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-9wCBts: Error opening directory '/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-9wCBts': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog:Mar  3 13:17:59 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2306]: Failed to enumerate children of /var/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-MZlaaA: Error opening directory '/var/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-MZlaaA': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog:Mar  3 13:17:59 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2306]: Failed to enumerate children of /tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-9wCBts: Error opening directory '/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-9wCBts': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog:Mar  3 14:17:59 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2306]: Failed to enumerate children of /var/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-MZlaaA: Error opening directory '/var/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-MZlaaA': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog:Mar  3 14:17:59 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2306]: Failed to enumerate children of /tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-9wCBts: Error opening directory '/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-9wCBts': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog:Mar  3 15:17:59 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2306]: Failed to enumerate children of /var/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-MZlaaA: Error opening directory '/var/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-MZlaaA': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog:Mar  3 15:17:59 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2306]: Failed to enumerate children of /tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-9wCBts: Error opening directory '/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-9wCBts': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog:Mar  3 16:17:59 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2306]: Failed to enumerate children of /var/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-MZlaaA: Error opening directory '/var/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-MZlaaA': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog:Mar  3 16:17:59 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2306]: Failed to enumerate children of /tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-9wCBts: Error opening directory '/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-9wCBts': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog:Mar  3 17:25:55 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2306]: Failed to enumerate children of /var/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-MZlaaA: Error opening directory '/var/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-MZlaaA': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog:Mar  3 17:25:55 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2306]: Failed to enumerate children of /tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-9wCBts: Error opening directory '/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-9wCBts': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog:Mar  3 18:25:55 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2306]: Failed to enumerate children of /var/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-MZlaaA: Error opening directory '/var/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-MZlaaA': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog:Mar  3 18:25:55 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2306]: Failed to enumerate children of /tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-9wCBts: Error opening directory '/tmp/systemd-private-3ac79b469d814451abc7a94863fa97be-colord.service-9wCBts': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog:Mar  3 18:27:36 ubu-desk dbus-daemon[1334]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' unit='colord.service' requested by ':1.64' (uid=121 pid=1727 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color " label="unconfined")
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 10:42:38 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[5923]: Failed to enumerate children of /var/tmp/systemd-private-16d192ca05624438bf88c70ad69b98dd-colord.service-h3RI7a: Error opening directory '/var/tmp/systemd-private-16d192ca05624438bf88c70ad69b98dd-colord.service-h3RI7a': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 10:42:38 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[5923]: Failed to enumerate children of /tmp/systemd-private-16d192ca05624438bf88c70ad69b98dd-colord.service-mpE8qo: Error opening directory '/tmp/systemd-private-16d192ca05624438bf88c70ad69b98dd-colord.service-mpE8qo': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 11:42:38 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[5923]: Failed to enumerate children of /var/tmp/systemd-private-16d192ca05624438bf88c70ad69b98dd-colord.service-h3RI7a: Error opening directory '/var/tmp/systemd-private-16d192ca05624438bf88c70ad69b98dd-colord.service-h3RI7a': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 11:42:38 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[5923]: Failed to enumerate children of /tmp/systemd-private-16d192ca05624438bf88c70ad69b98dd-colord.service-mpE8qo: Error opening directory '/tmp/systemd-private-16d192ca05624438bf88c70ad69b98dd-colord.service-mpE8qo': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 12:42:38 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[5923]: Failed to enumerate children of /var/tmp/systemd-private-16d192ca05624438bf88c70ad69b98dd-colord.service-h3RI7a: Error opening directory '/var/tmp/systemd-private-16d192ca05624438bf88c70ad69b98dd-colord.service-h3RI7a': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 12:42:38 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[5923]: Failed to enumerate children of /tmp/systemd-private-16d192ca05624438bf88c70ad69b98dd-colord.service-mpE8qo: Error opening directory '/tmp/systemd-private-16d192ca05624438bf88c70ad69b98dd-colord.service-mpE8qo': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 13:42:38 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[5923]: Failed to enumerate children of /var/tmp/systemd-private-16d192ca05624438bf88c70ad69b98dd-colord.service-h3RI7a: Error opening directory '/var/tmp/systemd-private-16d192ca05624438bf88c70ad69b98dd-colord.service-h3RI7a': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 13:42:38 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[5923]: Failed to enumerate children of /tmp/systemd-private-16d192ca05624438bf88c70ad69b98dd-colord.service-mpE8qo: Error opening directory '/tmp/systemd-private-16d192ca05624438bf88c70ad69b98dd-colord.service-mpE8qo': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 14:35:00 ubu-desk dbus-daemon[1388]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' unit='colord.service' requested by ':1.65' (uid=121 pid=1834 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color " label="unconfined")
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 15:28:21 ubu-desk dbus-daemon[1405]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' unit='colord.service' requested by ':1.67' (uid=121 pid=1841 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color " label="unconfined")
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 16:28:32 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2361]: Failed to enumerate children of /var/tmp/systemd-private-c8588750b47b4c078b0d7d3099120320-colord.service-YuKHaY: Error opening directory '/var/tmp/systemd-private-c8588750b47b4c078b0d7d3099120320-colord.service-YuKHaY': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 16:28:32 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2361]: Failed to enumerate children of /tmp/systemd-private-c8588750b47b4c078b0d7d3099120320-colord.service-DdQmvQ: Error opening directory '/tmp/systemd-private-c8588750b47b4c078b0d7d3099120320-colord.service-DdQmvQ': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 17:28:32 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2361]: Failed to enumerate children of /var/tmp/systemd-private-c8588750b47b4c078b0d7d3099120320-colord.service-YuKHaY: Error opening directory '/var/tmp/systemd-private-c8588750b47b4c078b0d7d3099120320-colord.service-YuKHaY': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 17:28:32 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2361]: Failed to enumerate children of /tmp/systemd-private-c8588750b47b4c078b0d7d3099120320-colord.service-DdQmvQ: Error opening directory '/tmp/systemd-private-c8588750b47b4c078b0d7d3099120320-colord.service-DdQmvQ': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 18:21:43 ubu-desk dbus-daemon[1470]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' unit='colord.service' requested by ':1.68' (uid=121 pid=1881 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color " label="unconfined")
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 18:23:06 ubu-desk dbus-daemon[1472]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' unit='colord.service' requested by ':1.66' (uid=121 pid=1882 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color " label="unconfined")
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 18:25:42 ubu-desk dbus-daemon[1399]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' unit='colord.service' requested by ':1.65' (uid=121 pid=1839 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color " label="unconfined")
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 19:18:17 ubu-desk dbus-daemon[1457]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' unit='colord.service' requested by ':1.66' (uid=121 pid=3187 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color " label="unconfined")
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 19:27:17 ubu-desk dbus-daemon[1383]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' unit='colord.service' requested by ':1.65' (uid=121 pid=1820 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color " label="unconfined")
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 19:41:18 ubu-desk dbus-daemon[1442]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' unit='colord.service' requested by ':1.62' (uid=121 pid=1802 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color " label="unconfined")
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 20:18:15 ubu-desk dbus-daemon[1435]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' unit='colord.service' requested by ':1.64' (uid=121 pid=1863 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color " label="unconfined")
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 20:22:28 ubu-desk dbus-daemon[1307]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' unit='colord.service' requested by ':1.63' (uid=121 pid=1650 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color " label="unconfined")
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 20:22:28 ubu-desk colord-sane: [bjnp] create_broadcast_socket: ERROR - bind socket to local address failed - Cannot assign requested address
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 20:40:50 ubu-desk dbus-daemon[1316]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' unit='colord.service' requested by ':1.63' (uid=121 pid=1711 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color " label="unconfined")
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 21:04:36 ubu-desk dbus-daemon[1301]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' unit='colord.service' requested by ':1.64' (uid=121 pid=1712 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color " label="unconfined")
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 21:09:15 ubu-desk dbus-daemon[1293]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' unit='colord.service' requested by ':1.65' (uid=121 pid=1650 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color " label="unconfined")
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 21:09:15 ubu-desk colord-sane: [bjnp] create_broadcast_socket: ERROR - bind socket to local address failed - Cannot assign requested address
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 22:09:22 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2237]: Failed to enumerate children of /var/tmp/systemd-private-708805c760d842af870d2f82461f9971-colord.service-hPnkcl: Error opening directory '/var/tmp/systemd-private-708805c760d842af870d2f82461f9971-colord.service-hPnkcl': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 22:09:22 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2237]: Failed to enumerate children of /tmp/systemd-private-708805c760d842af870d2f82461f9971-colord.service-qAVab7: Error opening directory '/tmp/systemd-private-708805c760d842af870d2f82461f9971-colord.service-qAVab7': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 23:09:22 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2237]: Failed to enumerate children of /var/tmp/systemd-private-708805c760d842af870d2f82461f9971-colord.service-hPnkcl: Error opening directory '/var/tmp/systemd-private-708805c760d842af870d2f82461f9971-colord.service-hPnkcl': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 23:09:22 ubu-desk gsd-housekeepin[2237]: Failed to enumerate children of /tmp/systemd-private-708805c760d842af870d2f82461f9971-colord.service-qAVab7: Error opening directory '/tmp/systemd-private-708805c760d842af870d2f82461f9971-colord.service-qAVab7': Permission denied
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 23:40:33 ubu-desk dbus-daemon[1299]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' unit='colord.service' requested by ':1.63' (uid=121 pid=1730 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color " label="unconfined")
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  2 23:40:33 ubu-desk colord-sane: [bjnp] create_broadcast_socket: ERROR - bind socket to local address failed - Cannot assign requested address
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  3 10:17:39 ubu-desk dbus-daemon[1302]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' unit='colord.service' requested by ':1.65' (uid=121 pid=1780 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color " label="unconfined")
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  3 10:17:39 ubu-desk colord-sane: [bjnp] create_broadcast_socket: ERROR - bind socket to local address failed - Cannot assign requested address
```

Comment: How did you get to this point? Something triggered it. Temporarily, you can switch to lighdm, just to see if the rest of the system is intact without gdm3. If it doesn't run ok, then a OS reinstall would be best. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` to use lightdm. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` to use gdm3.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for the lightdm tip, that does work. I don't know what caused the gdm issue, but perhaps it's related to the custom themes I installed or the gdm3 update from 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.3 to 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04 as the issue appeared around that time

Comment: When you added the gdm3 theme, did you place the files in ~/.themes? If so, rename the ~/.themes folder to ~/.themes.HOLD, then `dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`, reboot, and see what happens. Report back. Also, do `ls -al /home/user/.local/share/icc/edid-c1a0cd69078353a118ddc74a6c339113.icc` and see who owns the file.

Comment: Also, edit your question, and  show me `grep -i colord /var/log/syslog*` and `sudo systemctl status colord`.

Comment: @heynnema `/home/user/.local/share/icc/edid-c1a0cd69078353a118ddc74a6c339113.icc` is owned by user: `-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user` Don't have a ~/.themes directory, themes are in /usr/share/themes/

Comment: From the `ls -al` command, is user:user your username? Did you `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` yet? Do so, then use `gnome-tweaks` to reset your theme to `Adwaita`, reboot, and set if there's any improvement. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema user:user is an alias for my username, so yes I own the file. Didn't run  `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` as the ~/.theme folder doesn't exist and thus wasn't renamed.

Comment: You need to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`, as you're running on `lightdm` right now. Only then can you tell if the `Flat-Remix` theme really fixed your problem.

Comment: @heynnema Ah sorry - you're right I did run it to switch back to gdm3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When installing custom themes, you can install them for **system-wide use**, or **specific-user-only** use.

For **system-wide use**, you'll place theme files in `/usr/share/themes`.

For **specific-user-only** use, I recommend use use of the `User Themes` GNOME extension, which can be found [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/). For complete instructions on how to install this extension, see [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/05/enable-shell-theme-in-gnome-tweak-tool-in-ubuntu/). Then place custom themes into `~/.themes`. Use `gnome-tweaks` to select themes from this folder.

Be careful installing custom themes, as they can cause many system-wide problems, even if they're installed in a **specific-user-only** position.

**Update #1:**

The `Flat-Remix` theme, which was installed via apt, just offered an update. The update solved the gdm3 login screen issue.

Comment: Just so happened that one of my themes (Flat-Remix) which was installed via apt just offered an update. The update solved the gdm3 login screen issue. It is installed system-wide but perhaps that's not a great idea. The colord errors in syslog persist, as does the `failed to set screen _ICC_PROFILE` error. Would like to address these but I don't know what impact they have

Comment: @Karlito Good news. You didn't answer my questions in my last comment, above. Also, if my answer(s) were helpful in finding the problem, please remember to accept my answer by clicking the grey checkmark icon just to the left of my answer, and the grey up arrow icon for extra points. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry the comment was hidden, just responded. Any thoughts on the colord errors in syslog or the `failed to set screen _ICC_PROFILE` error? Or should I create a new question for those? Thanks

Comment: @Karlito I suspect that those errors are also related to theme issues. The only real way to tell is to temporarily run with the `Adwaita` theme, and see if the errors go away. If they don't, start new questions for those errors. Please remember the accept thingie for me.